# Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с синтаксисом

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с синтаксисом:

> После трагической гибели Павла I в Михайловском замке в ночь на 12 марта 1801 года Гатчина перешла в собственность его супруги Марии Федоровны, а затем владельцем загородной резиденции стал Николай I.

Сложносочиненное пр. с противительным союзом?

> При Александре II в 1857 году из Петергофа в Гатчину перевели Императорскую охоту, но государь приезжал во дворец редко, останавливаясь лишь на несколько дней.

Сложносочиненное пр. с противительным союзом и деепричастным оборотом?
Можно деепричастный оборот считать предикативной единицей?

Answer (score 2):

1) **Вид предложений  определен правильно, но есть дополнения.**

После трагической гибели Павла I в Михайловском замке в ночь на 12 марта 1801 года //Гатчина перешла в собственность его супруги Марии Федоровны, а затем владельцем загородной резиденции стал Николай I.

В начале ССП находится **общее распространенное обстоятельство,** отнесенное к обоим простым предложениям в составе ССП.

При Александре II в 1857 году из Петергофа в Гатчину перевели Императорскую охоту, но государь приезжал во дворец редко, останавливаясь лишь на несколько дней.

Деепричастный оборот относится **ко второму предложению.**

2) Деепричастный оборот не является предикативной единицей. Как  и другие обособленные члены (аналоги придаточных предложений), он соединяется с предложением  **полупредикативной связью.**

Обособленные обороты только относительно самостоятельны с точки зрения грамматики и смысла: они описывают **добавочную ситуацию**, **не связаны** с каким-либо членом предложения присловной связью и легко трансформируются в придаточные (определительные и обстоятельственные) предложения.

Но эта "предикация" не является самостоятельной и поэтому называется полупредикативной.